# Fill area With mouse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

What I want to do is very much clear in the attached image.[image]

I want to drag the cartoon face to draw line shown by red dots.If I drag it outside of the pattern it should revert to initial stage.
I have checked some canvas js libraries like paper.js,fabric.js, but couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: Now we know what you want to do, but what is your question? About finding a library?

Comment: And what approaches has yet been made? Show us some code snippets!

Comment: @Teemu I couldn't find a library which can be used for this functionality.Do have any idea  which library can i use?

Comment: @nedstark You've probably seen this: "`Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. `"

Comment: So if you drag outside "A", dots should disappear?

Comment: @nicael If i drag inside and follow the dots, then It will fill the area BUT if the I drag outside it filled area will disappear and dots will appear again and the carton face will be at its initial state

Comment: Your question is closed so I can't provide the details of an answer, but since I did something similar a while back I'll offer it up as a starting point for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YwP5p/